# Is there an equivalent of Snipping Tool for capturing video from a denoted area?

Tags: windows-10, video, screen-capture

There's a very handy application that comes with Windows 10 called [Snipping Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/13776/windows-use-snipping-tool-to-capture-screenshots) which allows me to capture a specific area of my screen.

The problem is that I can only capture a single image at a time.  Is there a tool out there that is just as simple to use that will allow me to select an area to capture a video?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Thank you.  I had not heard of softwarerecs until now.  Will use that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using OBS (Open Broadcaster oftware, https://obsproject.com) or CamStudio (http://camstudio.org), but I'm not sure if you can record only a certain area with CamStudio because I haven't used it

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. On-topic questions ask for a solution to a problem, and a software name is not a solution to an on-topic question.  It's OK to recommend software as part of an answer, but there are some minimum expectations.  It needs to add a lot more value than a random Google hit.  What makes it a good solution to the specific issue?  How do you use it to actually solve the problem? Good guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.

Comment: ah, sorry. I'll note that for later :)